UDP Multicast Windows
I have developed a C# application that needs to listen for UDP multicast messages. The UDP multicast is being sent from a Linux virtual machine (VM) with the following network details: inet: 192.168.6.101, multicast IP: 239.255.255.250, and port: 5697. When I run my C# application on the same Linux VM, it works as expected and is able to receive the multicast messages without any issues.
However, when I run the same application on a Windows machine with IP address 192.168.6.100, it does not seem to receive any multicast messages, despite the fact that I can see the multicast traffic coming in via Wireshark on the Windows machine.
It appears that the application is not able to pick up the incoming multicast messages on Windows, even though the network traffic is clearly present. Could there be an issue with how the multicast is handled on Windows, or do I need to configure something specific on the Windows system to allow the application to receive multicast traffic?
        string multicastIP = "239.255.255.250";
        int multicastPort = 5697;
        string localIP = "192.168.6.100";

        using (UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient())
        {
            udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            udpClient.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, multicastPort));
            udpClient.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse(multicastIP), IPAddress.Parse(localIP));
            udpClient.MulticastLoopback = true;

            IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, multicastPort);
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Listening for multicast messages...");

            while (true)
            {
                byte[] buffer = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEndPoint); 
                ...
            }


If i recall correctly Wireshark sees traffic even before the firewall. So if you see packages flowing in they might not get through the firewall. So open your system for Port 5697 if you haven't yet and/or shutdown the firewall or any other custom protection software that may block traffic.

Is UDP port open on windows machine? Windows firewall might be denying incoming UDP packets

@ZecosMAX I can't find my UDP port when I do this: netstat -an | find "UDP" | find "port_number"

I also added the port in the inbound rule of my firewall, but didn't change anything

Why are you mucking around with the raw socket in the first place, why not just use the UdpClient constructor to bind it? Also why are you setting localIP, why not use IPAdress.Any again?

Why did you tag this CAN bus?
